# Write SQL to find more than 2 of the same occurence and their name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL tables, and I am trying to pass a query that is supposed to tell my the department name with where there are more than 2 employees.

Employees:

```
+------+-----------+
| dept | firstname |
+------+-----------+
| 100  | name1     |
| 200  | name2     |
| 200  | name3     |
| 200  | name4     |
| 100  | name4     |
+------+-----------+
```

Departments

```
+--------+----------+
| deptID | deptName |
+--------+----------+
| 100    | Finance  |
| 200    | IT       |
+--------+----------+
```

My attempts:

```
SELECT deptName, dept, count(dept)>2 
FROM Employees, Departments GROUP by dept;
```

however it just returns itterations of "Finnance"

When I tried

```
SELECT dept, count(dept)>2 
FROM Employees GROUP by dept;
```

It returns Finance as 0 and IT as 1, so If I could find a way to find that "1" value and get it's deptName, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

In this case it should just return "IT" as IT is the only one with more than 2 employees. How could I write the query to get that?

Comment: Homework or assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select a.deptName, count(b.firstname) 
from departments a,
INNER JOIN  employees b ON a.deptID = b.dept
group by a.deptName
having count(b.firstname) >2;
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Do you mind explaining a bit what exactly that third line does? Mainly after the ON statement.

Comment: The HAVING clause is for conditions on aggregate functions. (Similar to WHERE.)

Comment: Well the 4th line lead the count saying count for each a.deptName, the 5th say : from all the results show only the row `having` more then 2

Comment: Having is an aggregate function and work on the result of a query and not on the selection of the row from the table...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

[`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html), [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/counting-rows.html) is what you want... now try to take a look on their man page.

Comment: Oops, this isn't really an answer. Should have been a comment instead.